# drumming -- voice as a 5th dimension of independence

Tags: drums, hand-independence

Working on 4 limb independence.  Counting beats or measures in my head (or out loud) is really hard.  4/4 I can just feel and seldom screw up, but I'm studying jazz and trying not to get lost doing things over the bar line, polyrhythms, fills, etc.  Do you have a solid counter in your head when playing?  Can you count using your voice all the quarter notes when doing complicated stuff?

I know musicians often do count (one-ee-and-a-two-ee etc) when practicing, but I'm specifically thinking of this as an exercise in independence.  How does a jazz musician deal with playing a long solo, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting is an excellent and important tool for *learning* and *practice* for all musicians who can count (i.e., those not playing breath operated instruments). But it doesn't present a professional image on stage. Many musicians tap their feet or user other tricks to keep time, but that can also be judged harshly by (some) audience members.

Drummers, and jazz drummers seem to do this more than most, IMHO, have some ways to "count" without using their mouths that are not judged harshly. The number one way is to keep the beat using the high hat pedal. I find keeping time on the high hat to be very difficult, but it definitely helps. It is yet another challenge of independence. It doesn't take much looking at professional drummers of all genres to find many examples of drummers who keep the hats going while playing fills, solos, and even ride cymbal patterns. One completely non-jazz example is John Bonham from Led Zeppelin. Keeping time on the hats also helps other musicians in the band keep track of the rhythm so they can time their return after a drum solo or stay synchronized during a fill.

I often sing along with the singer or hum the bass part while I drum. It's not as solid as counting for keeping time, but it does help me keep track of where I am, especially for very repetitive patterns. I learned to sing while playing other instruments before I got serious about drumming so I don't know as much about the challenges of adding a fifth independent "voice". I do know that counting, singing, and humming while you play is a great skill to learn and develop to help you keep time and improve your general musicianship.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to investigate the voice as a 5th degree of independence, then try actually singing or indeed rapping.

You can simplify the drum part until you get the hang of it, but maybe try playing along to something already known to demonstrate that type of independence [even if it was on a different instrument].
Songs by The Police or Thin Lizzy show great independence of vocal from instrument & core rhythm & are really quite demanding to learn.

One example - Boys are Back in Town - the vocal drifts across the beat as though the singer had nothing else to concentrate on; yet we all know that he was actually keeping a magnificently-swung 4 to the floor right the way through it.

If that's not challenging enough - try some Eminem, or perhaps simpler, Will Smith. That will keep you on your toes.

*Source for this - I've had to do all the above live, it sure teaches you how to do it ;)*

Comment: Or Rage Against The Machine. I love singing while drumming. It’s a shame that it’s a bad place for a vocal mic and that I get more winded drumming than playing any other instrument.